# Fulltext order by id slow

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search, fulltext-index

Fulltext search order by score and Id (if score the same) is very slow:

```
SELECT posts.*, MATCH (heading) AGAINST ('+book' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score 
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (heading) AGAINST ('+book' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC;
```

But if I remove ordering by primary key, the performance is much better:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (heading) AGAINST ('+book' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

As I understand, it sorts by score and ID asc by default

Not only score but freshness is also important, this is why If the score is the same, the newer post should rank first.

**Update**
Someone marked the question as duplicate. But It is not. Another post required an order by ID only. My question is order by score and ID if the scores are the same

Comment: Do you have a composite index on score and id columns? Please copy the results of the explain into the question!

Comment: @Shadow No, only heading column has been Fulltext indexed

Comment: Is there a `LIMIT` clause?  How many rows does it find?  Are you really doing `SELECT *`?  Can you use fewer columns -- to avoid shoveling around bulky columns?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`